# Laravel 4 - Illuminate \ Session \ TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to log-in into the application.

I got this error

[image]

---

**route**

`Route::post('/login','AuthController@postLogin');`

---

**I've tried**

`dd('HERE')` inside the controller, I don't see anything print out.

---

I've not work on Laravel 4 project for a while now, what should I look in order to by pass this error ?

Answer (score 0):

first use the a filter that passed the correct csrf_token

```
Route::post('register', array('before' => 'csrf'));
```

then add the input token in your form submit

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>
```

[**Source**](http://laraveldaily.com/csrf-protection-difference-laravel-4-x-5-0-and-5-1/)

Comment: I don't see that folder on **Laravel 4**.

Comment: @ihue I haven't notice you put laravel 4. I thought I was 5. So I updated my answer now. Please take a look

Comment: I am not sure if that the cause of my issue. I have the same codebase, and I can log-in fine on my production environment. Do you aggree ?